# GGPlot2 called twice inside a function only produces one plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am fairly new to ggplot2, so this may be a simple mistake that I am not aware of.

I am using this function to create violin plots of some data of mine. The data in question is Log fold change between two conditions of ChIP-seq reads for two proteins which we suspect follow RNAPII during transcription, but I don't think it's really relevant. The only thing is, I'd like the function to create two plots: one for genes that show an increase of RNAPII in the treatment condition, and one for genes that show a decrease.

```
Vioplot_LogFC = function(quant1, quant2, f, info = c("Quantif 1", "Quantif 2", "Factor")){


quant1_s = sample(quant1, length(f$top))
quant1_f = quant1[f$top]
quant2_s = sample(quant2, length(f$top))
quant2_f = quant2[f$top]

LogFC = c(quant1_s, quant1_f, quant2_s, quant2_f)
Factor = c(rep(info[1], length(quant1_s)+length(quant1_f)), rep(info[2], length(quant2_s)+length(quant2_f)))
Group = c(rep("Random", length(quant1_s)), rep("PolII increase", length(quant1_f)), rep("Random", length(quant2_s)), rep("PolII increase", length(quant2_f)))

toplot=data.frame(LogFC, Factor, Group)

p1 = floor(-1*log10(wilcox.test(quant1_f, quant1_s)$p.value))
p2 = floor(-1*log10(wilcox.test(quant2_f, quant2_s)$p.value))

label1 = paste0(info[1],"; p<10^-", p1)
label2 = paste0(info[2],"; p<10^-", p2)

plot1 = ggplot(toplot, aes(x=Factor, y=LogFC, fill=Group)) +
    geom_violin() +
    scale_x_discrete(labels=c(label1, label2)) +
    scale_y_continuous(name="Log Fold Change") +
    scale_fill_discrete(name="Gene Group") +
    theme_bw()

##################################
##################################
##################################

quant1_s = sample(quant1, length(f$bot))
quant1_f = quant1[f$bot]
quant2_s = sample(quant2, length(f$bot))
quant2_f = quant2[f$bot]

LogFC = c(quant1_s, quant1_f, quant2_s, quant2_f)
Factor = c(rep(info[1], length(quant1_s)+length(quant1_f)), rep(info[2], length(quant2_s)+length(quant2_f)))
Group = c(rep("Random", length(quant1_s)), rep("PolII decrease", length(quant1_f)), rep("Random", length(quant2_s)), rep("PolII decrease", length(quant2_f)))

toplot=data.frame(LogFC, Factor, Group)

p1 = floor(-1*log10(wilcox.test(quant1_f, quant1_s)$p.value))
p2 = floor(-1*log10(wilcox.test(quant2_f, quant2_s)$p.value))

label1 = paste0(info[1],"; p<10^-", p1)
label2 = paste0(info[2],"; p<10^-", p2)
plot2 = ggplot(toplot, aes(x=Factor, y=LogFC, fill=Group)) +
    geom_violin() +
    scale_x_discrete(labels=c(label1, label2)) +
    scale_y_continuous(name="Log Fold Change") +
    scale_fill_discrete(name="Gene Group") +
    theme_bw()

plot1
plot2


}
```

I always use this function inside `pdf(...) dev.off()`, and yet the pdf contains only one plot.

Is it some issue due to using the same data & names twice? Is there a `clear()` function I should use after creating the first plot to be able to create a new one?

Comment: plot2 will replace plot1 on your device.. load library(gridExtra); and on the last line; instead of plot1 plot2, do grid.arrange(plot1,plot2)

Comment: A function in R returns the last line it executes. So it will return `plot2`. You could just save the plots with `+ ggsave("filename.png")`

Comment: I think you might also be able to store your plots as a list: `return(list(plot1, plot2))`

Comment: @JackBrookes When I use basic R functions, I can use `boxplot(...) boxplot(...)` and it will create two plots.

Comment: @StupidWolf Will that not "squish" the two plots one on top of the other onto one page? I'd rather have two pages? (see my edit of the question, forgot to specify something)

Comment: @Michael that worked! Want to write it out as an answer?

Comment: Oh i see, yeah use @Michael suggestion, return(list(plot1, plot2)). so after that run it, PLOTS = Vioplot_LogFC(...); pdf("test.pdf"); print(PLOTS[[1]]); print(PLOTS[[2]]) ; dev.off()

Comment: @StupidWolf I don't even need to go through the PLOTS object, I can just do `pdf("test.pdf"); Vioplot_LogFC(...); dev.off()`

Comment: yeah I am aware of that. Just nicer if you store your plots, imagine something is weird, you can still check what is in the plot object stored.. everything gets lost once you exit the function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @StupidWolf noted, R functions will return the last line by default (and not previous objects). You can adjust your function to return whatever you want, though, using `return`.

ggplot objects may be stored in a list and retrieved. Thus instead of

```
plot1
plot2
```

in which case only `plot2` is returned, you could end your function with

```
 return(list(plot1, plot2))
```

Now the output of your function is a list with 2 elements, `plot1` and `plot2`. as @StupidWolf noted, you can print and save these plots by calling them from the list using the double square brackets, so if you did

```
 PLOTS<-Vioplot_logFC(...)
```

you could retrieve, print, or manipulate plot1 using

```
 PLOTS[[1]]]
```

As an example of "manipulate" you could change the "theme" post-hoc, e.g.

```
 PLOTS[[1]]+theme_classic()
```

Comment: Also, you can get both plots as one with ggpubr package. The code would be: ggpubr::ggarrange(plot1,plot2,nrow=2,ncol=1).

Comment: @SantiagoI.Hurtado As I said in the comments, this can be used but will "squish" the two plots onto one page if you're using `pdf()`, whereas I'd prefer to keep them on different pages for ease of reading.